# Chart.js two columns on page - left column is squished until page resize

Tags: html, chart.js

**Details:**

I'm using Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/) for displaying responsive charts in .jsps on a Tomcat server. Seem to be working fine almost everywhere. I'm setting the max-width of the canvas and setting the charts to responsive, so they can resize to fill the whole container as the window resizes.

**Problem:**

When I've got a page with two columns of charts, I think the right column is squishing the left column container (and chart) back, but the chart is not properly resizing. See the Plunker to see how squished everything looks in the left column. I've played with maintaining aspect ratio/not. I've also tried running a .resize() on window load, but it didn't seem to work either. (would rather not have to do this, since I may have any number of charts in the left column and don't want to resize all of them). Any advice is appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="vertical-align: top">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center" colspan="2">
              <table border="0" width="99%">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="left" width="48%">
                    <table border=0 class="tableBoxed" width="98%">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="THCell" valign="top">
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="THCellChart" valign="top" align="right">
                          <style type="text/css">
                            #myChart_0{
                              width: 100% !important;
                              max-width: 1400px;
                              height: 350px !important;
                            }
                          </style>
                          Chart 1 
                          <div> 
                            <canvas id="myChart_0"> 
                              <script type="text/javascript"> 
                                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_0"); 
                                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {  
                                  options: {    
                                    animation: {        
                                      animateScale:true
                                    },      
                                    maintainAspectRatio: false,     
                                    responsive: true,       
                                    legend: {           
                                      display: false
                                    },      
                                    tooltips: {         
                                      mode: 'label'
                                    }
                                  },    
                                  type: 'line',     
                                  data: {       
                                    labels: ['22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
                                    datasets: [{            
                                      label: ['Probability (%)'],           
                                      fill: false,          
                                      data: [3.600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.100, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],            
                                      borderColor: '#00929F',           
                                      backgroundColor: '#00929F',           
                                      borderCapStyle: 'butt',           
                                      borderDash: [],           
                                      borderDashOffset: 0.0,            
                                      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',             
                                      pointBorderColor:  '#F08000',             
                                      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',             
                                      pointBorderWidth: 1,          
                                      pointHoverRadius: 5,          
                                      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#00929F',             
                                      pointHoverBorderColor:  '#F08000',            
                                      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,             
                                      pointRadius: 2,           
                                      pointHitRadius: 4
                                    }]
                                  }
                                }); 
                              </script>
                            </canvas>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td valign="top" align="right" width="50%">
                    <table border=0 class="tableBoxed" width="98%">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="THCell" valign="top">
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="THCellChart" valign="top" align="right">
                          <style type="text/css">
                            #myChart_1{
                              width: 100% !important;
                              max-width: 1400px;
                              height: 350px !important;
                            }
                          </style>
                          Chart 2 
                          <div> 
                            <canvas id="myChart_1"> 
                              <script type="text/javascript"> 
                                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_1"); 
                                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {  
                                  options: {    
                                    animation: {        
                                      animateScale:true
                                    },      
                                    maintainAspectRatio: false,     
                                    responsive: true,       
                                    legend: {           
                                      display: false
                                    },      
                                    tooltips: {         
                                      mode: 'label'
                                    }
                                  },    
                                  type: 'line',     
                                  data: {       
                                    labels: ['22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42'],
                                    datasets: [{            
                                      label: ['Probability (%)'],           
                                      fill: false,          
                                      data: [3.600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.100, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],            
                                      borderColor: '#00929F',           
                                      backgroundColor: '#00929F',           
                                      borderCapStyle: 'butt',           
                                      borderDash: [],           
                                      borderDashOffset: 0.0,            
                                      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',             
                                      pointBorderColor:  '#F08000',             
                                      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',             
                                      pointBorderWidth: 1,          
                                      pointHoverRadius: 5,          
                                      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#00929F',             
                                      pointHoverBorderColor:  '#F08000',            
                                      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,             
                                      pointRadius: 2,           
                                      pointHitRadius: 4
                                    }]
                                  }
                                }); 
                              </script>
                            </canvas>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </center>
    <script>
        function updateChart () {
            myChart_0.resize();
        }
        window.onload (updateChart());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Plunker:** https://plnkr.co/edit/fDZDYhFykXIAQfmBgsY2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've figured this out, hopefully if someone ever stumbles into this I can help.

I know it's bad practice to use tables for site layout, but the code I picked this up from already had that in place so I stuck with it. Well, months later, that came back to bite me when I added Chart.js. Placing each of the charts in a leftDiv and rightDiv class made everything work fine.